# Why is web deploy not using the correct web.config transform?

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

I am trying to publish in VS 2012 using a build configuration called "CI" but when I execute the publish, the "Release" transform (web.Release.config) is used on web.config.  How do I get web.CI.config to be applied instead?  *I thought this would be automatic.*

I have conducted a few experiments which confirm this.

Has anyone seen this?  Is this a (fixed) bug?

Comment: 4 years later (using VS 2015) and still encountered this problem. The accepted answer worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes configurations get messed up depending on how you added the configuration. To fix this, close visual studio, open your solution(.sln) file in an text editor. Under `GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution` section you might see something like this

`{427E2FA3-1BAE-4A03-A712-C951ECEC45A3}.CI|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU`
`{427E2FA3-1BAE-4A03-A712-C951ECEC45A3}.CI|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU`

Notice that `CI` is equating to `Release`. Change the above to

`{427E2FA3-1BAE-4A03-A712-C951ECEC45A3}.CI|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = CI|Any CPU`
`{427E2FA3-1BAE-4A03-A712-C951ECEC45A3}.CI|Any CPU.Build.0 = CI|Any CPU`

Reload solution in visual studio and try publishing again.

Comment: Absolutely the correct answer.  However, I found a bunch of these mistakes (of the same pattern) and had to make sure I fixed all of them. Do you know if this problem survived into VS 2013 or was it fixed?

Comment: This happens in all visual studios. When you create a new configuration you get an option "Copy setting from" we usually end up choosing one of the existing configurations. That's when we get these weird setting in the sln file. I think if we choose the create empty option, this problem does not occur.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. This is so typical Microsoft, it makes my head spin.
I had to use the configuration manager to explicitly create a "Stage" configuration so that my web.stage.config is actually used during publish.